# How can i use timelines in version svg.js 3.x

Tags: svg.js

There seems to be a new timeline-feature in svg.js Version 3.x. I'd like to try this feature but I don't understand the api. As far as I see, the documentation has not been updated yet. Could you please give me an example that shows me how to get started with timelines?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new timeline is created for every element automatically when you animate it or request it:

```
const animationRunner = el.animate(duration).move(100, 100) // cretates a timeline
const timeline = el.timeline() // also creates a timeline if not present
```

However, often you want to schedule animation of different elements on the same timeline. Therefore you can also create a timeline first and then set it on the element:

```
const timeline = new SVG.Timeline() // create a timeline
el.timeline(timeline) // set the timeline for the element
```

Animations are scheduled on the timeline automatically when you animate an element. As a default behavior, they are scheduled to run after the last animation which was scheduled on the timeline. If no animation was scheduled, then it will run right away:

```
el.animate(1000).move(100, 100) // moves now
  .animate(1000).move(200, 200) // moves after first animation
```

To have more control over the scheduling you can pass additional parameters to animate:

```
el.animate(duration, delay, when)
```

- duration: duration of the animation. Can be a number or a controller in which case it is not a duration and the whole animation is controlled by the controller
- delay: time before the animaton starts
- when: can be 'now', 'relative', 'after' or 'absolut'

  - now: run right away
  - relative: start after `delay` ms relative to the start of the animation before
  - after: start `delay` ms after the last animation was finished
  - absolute: place the animation `delay` ms of the zero of the timeline

To conrol the timeline, you can use `play()`, `pause()`, `stop()`, `finish()`, `seek()`, `speed()`, `reverse()` and so on.

If you want to play around with this, you shall also use `persist(true)` on the timeline. Otherwise animations which are finished are garbage collected and unscheduled from the timeline automatically.

As spoiled in the first code example, `animate()` returns an animationRunner (short `Runner`) which holds all infos about the animation. You can schedule those Runners directly on the timeline by using `schedule` or `unschedule`. However, I think this will burst the frame of this answer.

A good example for the end: https://codepen.io/fuzzyma/pen/wQbVed
And many other examples with animations: https://codepen.io/collection/XpwMLO/#