# SVG.js how to loop through multiple animation steps

Tags: loops, svg, svg.js

i am new to using svg.js. I want to animate an element from it's original position to a second position and back to the original position and loop that process. What's the bets wa for achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of svg.js are you using?

Comment: version 2.7 :) the newest i guess

Comment: 3.0.12 is the newest. You can install it with `npm i @svgdotjs/svg.js`

Comment: Ty :) i will do it. Do you have an idea how i can sole my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Edit: Just use the loop() method to loop animations

For longer animation chains you need the following solution:

For svg v2.x it is not really possible in a build-in way. You can write a function which sets the whole animation chain up and call it after the animation finished (with the `afterAll()` method)

In svg v3.x you can setup a timeline and move in time to replay animations.
You can read more on this in this answer:
[How can i use timelines in version svg.js 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762861/how-can-i-use-timelines-in-version-svg-js-3-x/54783645#54783645)

Comment: I am not sure if i explained myself very well. I just need to move an object from A to B than back to A and that with loop() .  Is there a simple way to do this

Comment: Yes, loop(true, true)

Comment: Scissors.animate(1000, '-').move(25, 260).move(25, 250).loop(true, true) ? Does not work. AM i doing sthing wrong?

Comment: Only one move command is needed. The object then moves force and back between initial position and position specfied in love. You can see example codes in the docs :)